# Custom Query Pagination Cakephp

Tags: mysql, cakephp, pagination

I have a custom query in my controller and I would like to implement the custom query pagination I found on cakephp.org but their example is not similar to mine.  Can someone please help me paginate this result in my view:

```
    $cars = $this->Car->query(" select Car.id, Car.make, Car.model, Car.year, Car.description, CarImage.thumbnail
                                    from cars Car
                                    inner join car_images CarImage on Car.default_image_id = CarImage.id
                                    where Car.make like '" . $category . "'
                                    order by Car.created DESC
                                    limit 10");
    $this->set('cars', $cars);
```

Answer (score 4):

Implement paginate and paginateCount in your model:

```
function paginate($conditions, $fields, $order, $limit, $page, $recursive, $extra)
{
    return $this->query('SELECT ...');
}

function paginateCount($conditions, $recursive, $extra)
{
    return $this->query('SELECT COUNT(.....');
}
```

Also check out the paginate function in: cake/libs/controller/controller.php

Answer (score 2):

This looks like it should be able to be done without resorting to using custom pagination.

You should set in the following relationships in your models:

Car hasMany (or hasOne) CarImage  
CarImage belongsTo Car

Then you should be able to get this exact data using the following:

```
<?php
class CarsController extends AppController {
  var $paginate = array('limit'=>'10',
                        'order'=>'Car.created',
                        'fields'=>array('Car.model','Car.year','Car.description',
                                        'CarImage.thumbnail'));

  function test() {
    // not sure where you are getting the where clause, if its from some form
    // you'll want to check look in $this->data
    $category = "somevalue";
    // set the LIKE condition
    $conditions = array('Car.make LIKE' => '%'.$category.'%');
    // apply the custom conditions to the pagination
    $this->set('cars', $this->paginate($conditions);
  }
}
?>
```

For more information on complex find conditions (which can be applied to paginate by passing in an array like I did in the above example): http://book.cakephp.org/view/74/Complex-Find-Conditions

Comment: how about when the query calls a stored procedure that returns a resultset which is not that model? ie. returns a different table structure than the model. how can you paginate such a scenario?
i have this function in the model `public function GetSummary(){
     $sql="CALL main_report()";
     return $this->query($sql);
  }`

Answer (score 1):

In Cake 3 you can use de the deafult paginator with function find() .

Follow the example:

```
$query = $this->Car->find()
                ->select(['Car.id', 'Car.make','Car.model','Car.year','Car.description','CarImage.thumbnail'])
                ->join([
                        'table' => 'CarImage',
                        'alias' => 'CarImage',
                        'type' => 'INNER',
                        'conditions' => 'CarImage.id = Car.default_image_id,
                ])
                ->where(['Car.make LIKE' => '%$category%'])
                ->order(['Car.created' => 'DESC'])
                ->limit(50)

        $cars = $this->paginate($query);

        $this->set(compact('cars'));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['cars']);
```

Answer (score 0):

mysql limit clause support volume and offset, so 10 results per page....

```
select * from table limit 0, 10
```

page 1

```
select * from table limit 10, 10
```

page 2

```
select * from table limit 20, 10
```

page 3

```
select * from table limit ($page-1)*$perPage, $perPage
```

Generic

Comment: I was hoping for something that uses the paginate function in cakephp

Answer (score 0):

mysql limit clause support volume and offset, so 10 results per page....