# CakePHP Pagination on array variable

Tags: php, arrays, pagination, cakephp-2.0

I try to use the paginate class into CakePhp having the query results created by a custom method and not in the traditional CakePHP way .

At the end i have an array.

I try to apply the paginate into this array but did not see it paginating :

`$myArray = $this->myModel->SearchDatabaseData( );
$myArray = $this->paginate('myModel');`

The query is made into a Component so it claims for a Model instance instead 
`PaginatorComponent::validateSort() must be an instance of Model, instance of VerificacaoComponent given`

Can i apply CakePHP pagination into a custom made array ?

I am using CakePhp 2.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Cakephp Custom query pagination.
This requires 2 functions in your model, one with the query it self and another one with a count query with the same conditions.

When you try to paginate in your model, CakePhp has 2 global functions in the main AppModel, basically you will override this 2 functions rewriting them in your model.

This functions are: **paginate()** and **paginateCount()**

Once you override the AppModel functions with your custom version in your model, you can use regular **$this->YourModelName->paginate();** in your controller.

You can find examples in this StackOverflow question: 
[Custom Query Pagination Cakephp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1850538/custom-query-pagination-cakephp)

You can check the original documentation here:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html#custom-query-pagination